# Unknown Reason for App Locale Encrypted During Render?

Tags: laravel, localization, locale

I am having an unusual issue.

I have a multi tenant Laravel app that uses app()->setLocale() for setting the default locale for the tenant

When I get the locale in the view/controller for any tenant or the root app I get a encrypted string like this:
`eyJpdiI6ImtMdFI5Q05KSkU0WlJGaG9HUnF4K2c9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoic3ZVXC90SzVRRjBhUkpQdHJmcHNDUlE9PSIsIm1hYyI6IjE3MDQ4MjBiYTg0YzgwMWRmZmZlMTYxN2EwNDkwODE2MGJmZTNmNDJjOTAwYmE0ZGVlOWY0Yjc4YjIyNmEyMTAifQ==`

but if I get it from the AppServiceProvider just after I set it I the correct result like:
`en_AU`

My composer.json:

```
"require": {
    "php": "^7.2",
    "appstract/laravel-options": "^2.2",
    "fideloper/proxy": "^4.0",
    "laravel/framework": "^6.2",
    "laravel/passport": "^7.5",
    "laravel/telescope": "^2.1",
    "laravel/tinker": "^1.0",
    "spatie/laravel-activitylog": "^3.9",
    "spatie/laravel-query-builder": "^2.3",
    "spatie/laravel-schemaless-attributes": "^1.6",
    "spatie/laravel-sluggable": "^2.2",
    "spatie/laravel-translatable": "^4.2",
    "stancl/tenancy": "^2.1"
},
"require-dev": {
    "ahuggins/open-on-make": "^0.0.37",
    "ajthinking/tinx": "^2.6",
    "facade/ignition": "^1.4",
    "fzaninotto/faker": "^1.4",
    "laravel/homestead": "^9.2",
    "laravel/ui": "^1.1",
    "mockery/mockery": "^1.0",
    "nunomaduro/collision": "^3.0",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "^8.0"
}
```

My AppServiceProvider boot contains this code to change the timezone and locale:

```
Tenancy::hook('bootstrapped', function ($tenantManager) {
    if (Schema::hasTable('options')) {
        // Set Tenant Timezone
        if (option_exists('timezone')) {
            $timezone = option('timezone');
            config(['app.timezone' => $timezone]);
            date_default_timezone_set($timezone);
        }

        // Set Tenant Local
        logger('Option: ' . option('locale', 'en'));
        app()->setLocale(option('locale', 'en'));
        logger('App: ' . app()->getLocale());
    }
});

Tenancy::hook('ended', function ($tenantManager) {
    if (Schema::hasTable('options')) {
        // Reset Timezone
        $timezone = env('APP_TIMEZONE', 'Australia/Adelaide');
        config(['app.timezone' => $timezone]);
        date_default_timezone_set($timezone);

        //Reset Local
        app()->setLocale(env('APP_LOCALE', 'en_AU'));
    }
});
```

I have tried even as simple a route as this:

```
Route::get('', function () {
    return app()->getLocate();
}
```

and still no luck

I have also tried:

- Removing the above code in the AppServiceProvider
- A fresh Laravel install and installing all the same packages and managed to recreate it once with the install/uninstall of ahiggins/open-on-make.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok So it turns out the issue is with a middleware that I created to save the users language option to a cookie value.

The problem was that if one did not exist I set the language to false and hence the long string.

The Middleware would then grab this value each time the user loaded the page.